# Iterate Multiple Nested Lists in Flask Template using For loop

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, nested-loops

I have Python list like the following

> [[1, 'sarmad ali', 10], [2, 'nabeel', 200], [3, ' tayyab', 40202]]

I want to show them in a table/two dimensional style in template(html page) the following

> 1    sarmad ali    10
>
> 2    nabeel         200
>
> 3 tayyab    40202

I am able to got the following

> 1  sarmad ali  10  2   nabeel  200 3   tayyab  40202

In my python file I have data in the form of `Dataframe`, and converted to `list`.

```
{% for col in data_list%}
    
    {% for row in col%}
        
        <td>{{row}}</td>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    <br>

{% endfor %}
```

The above nested loop is producing the output in single line instead of table format.
**I figured out that second loop is iterating all the lists in single line instead of iterating single list at a time**

Feel free to ask any question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i am using in my template file to display the list.

```
<div class="content-section">
    <legend class="mb-4"> Table </legend>
<table class="table" >
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      {%for i in columns%}
      <th scope="col">{{i[0]}}</th>
      {%endfor%}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {%for i in result%}

    <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
          {%for k in i%}
          <td>{{k}}</td>
          {%endfor%}
      </tr>

    {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
{% for sno, name, rank in data_list%}
   <tr>
     <td>{{sno}}</td>
     <td>{{name}}</td>
     <td>{{rank}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Edited:
Suppose if you don't know the number of items in the list,

```
<table>
{% for tr in data_list%}
   <tr>
   {% for td in data_list%}
     <td>{{td}}</td>
    {% endfor%}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Loop atributes are not known, they can by more then three (sno, name, rank, etc).

Comment: You can run one more loop for that.